# Sequelize [object SequelizeModel] save is not a function

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, insert, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize with Node and I have an instance of a model called athlete. I'm trying to insert it into my database using the save() function but it is returning this:

```
TypeError: athlete.save is not a function
```

Here is my code snippet :

```
console.log("Athlete: " + athlete);
athlete.save().then(function() {
    console.log("Inserted Athlete");
    callback(null, athlete);
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log("Inserted athlete with error: " + err);
    callback(err, null);
});
```

The log prints this:

```
Athlete: [object SequelizeModel]
```

athlete is created from a class method in a Sequelize model definition file.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out SequelizeModel is not the correct type of object. It needs to be an object of type SequelizeInstance in order to be saved using the save() function.

Comment: by using model.build({}) eg ` Athlete.build ( {name: 'Darren', age: 28} ) `

Answer (score 0):

Try do build your instance before save:

```
    const athlete = Athlete.build(req.body,
        {
        fields: ['athlete']
        })
    .save()
    .then( // . //)
    .catch(err => {res.json(err)})
```